# Changing CSS display style with javascript

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following html code for my php page.

```
<span id="edit_button_<?php echo $row[$id]; ?>" style="display:block;" onClick="editRow(this, '');"><img src="images/edit.png" />
<span id="edit_save_<?php echo $row[$id]; ?>" style="display:none;" onClick="saveRow(this,'');"><img src="images/green_check.png" />
<span id="edit_cancel_<?php echo $row[$id]; ?>" style="display:none;" onClick="cancelEdit(this, '');"><img src="images/red_cross.png" />
```

In the `editRow()` function, I added the following lines to make the `#edit_save_` and `#edit_cancel_` elements visible:

```
$('#edit_save_'+id).show();
$('#edit_cancel_'+id).show();
```

But they are not getting displayed. I then added the following lines as well, but it didn't work either:

```
document.getElementById('edit_save_'+releaseTable+relPid).style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('edit_cancel_'+releaseTable+relPid).style.display = 'block';
```

Strangely, the issue is only with some of the records. Like row 1 is showing green_check and red_cross images, but row 2 doesn't.

Comment: Another strange thing is, it works sometimes on my local machine, it doesn't work sometimes. But when I deployed to dev region, it doesnt work at all.

Comment: Your spans don't have closing tags. That could make quite a mess in your DOM. And, consequently, non-working js operations on those elements.

Comment: Can you please post your edit_row function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the first row is working but the subsequent rows are not is because you can't have multiple rows with the same `ID`s. Unlike jQuery `class` selectors, `ID` selectors will find the 1st match and only that match, which in your case is that first row.

Also, it is preferable not to have your JavaScript `inline` with your HTML. This is what people call "separation of concerns" or ["separation of presentation and logic"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046051/separation-of-presentation-and-business-logic-in-php) or any permutations of that. It is best to put the Javascript within a `<script>` tag either on the same page as your PHP or preferably as an external script.

so instead of this inline function call:

```
<span onclick="editRow()"></span>
```

you would do this:

```
<script>
      $('span').on('click', function(){
           //call editRow(); 
           // or make other javascript which performs editRow function (toggle display)
       });           
</script>
```

To get back to your scenario and overcome this issue with using an `ID`-based selector, add a class to each clickable button, `edit_button`, like this:

HTML:

```
<span class="edit_button" data-id="<?php echo $row[$id]; ?>" id="edit_button_<?php echo $row[$id]; ?>" style="display:block;" ><img src="images/edit.png" /></span>
<span id="edit_save_<?php echo $row[$id]; ?>" style="display:none;" onClick="saveRow(this,'');"><img src="images/green_check.png" /></span>
<span id="edit_cancel_<?php echo $row[$id]; ?>" class="cancel_button" data-id="<?php echo $row[$id]; ?>" style="display:none;" ><img src="images/red_cross.png" /></span>
```

this is then what the JS looks like:

```
$('.edit_button').on('click', function(){
    var id=$(this).data('id');
    $(this).toggle();
    $('#edit_save_'+id).toggle();
    $('#edit_cancel_'+id).toggle(); 
});

$('.cancel_button').on('click', function(){
    var id=$(this).data('id');
    $(this).toggle();
    $('#edit_save_'+id).toggle();
    $('#edit_button_'+id).toggle(); 
});
```

Please see this JSfiddle where I've taken the PHP out of it. I believe it shows the behavior that you're interested in: http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/vLMCh/14/

Lastly, please add closing `</span>` tags.

Comment: He add row_id at the end of his spans IDs, why you think they aren't unicum?

Comment: Unless `$row[$id]` is unique for each row, which I'd assume it is. Then setting the ID like the OP is doing now is fine...

Comment: @subhaze thanks for the clarification, i assumed the `id`'s were unique too.

Comment: the $row[$id] is unique here. But I still changed the element ids to class, no luck..

Comment: @user1165952 check out this JSfiddle, i took the PHP out of it and it seems to give what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/vLMCh/3/

Comment: @timpeterson I donnno, when I comment document.getelementbyid, it's still giving the same result. And I dunno how this code is different from mine?? Am I missing something??

Comment: @user1165952 still having problems? or are you ok now? if solved, could you accept an answer?

Comment: Nope, still having problems, doesn't make sense at all.. how it sometimes works and sometimes not in local machine. Whenever it works, it's taking style "display: inline". In dev, it never worked. has it to do something with php version? In local, i have MAMP (php 5.3.6). In dev, i have LAMP (5.1.6).

Comment: @user1165952 can you try this jsfiddle to let me know is this is the behavior you are interested in: http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/vLMCh/12/

Comment: this is kinda what i need, but edit_1 image should disappear on clicking it and reappear when i click cancel image.. Thanks for all your effort!!

Comment: this looks perfect in jsfiddle, but the edit image is not disappearing in my actual code. I put this code in editRow function

Comment: @user1165952 that's because `this` isn't the same as `$(this)`. The first is javascript, the 2nd is jQuery. So you can't do `this.toggle();` Just get rid of the `this` in your `editRow` function and do it the jQuery way.

Comment: @user1165952 As I said in my answer above, it is generally agreed that "inline" javascript, `onclick="editRow()"`, is bad form. I'd stick to the format I did in my jsfiddle as this is what you'll be seeing most people doing as you get into jquery/javascript more and more.

Comment: @timpeterson If editRow() function is removed, where do I put my jquery code? in document.ready? I'm very new to javascript and jquery and they both make me crazy with weird things. I just have existing code and I'm maintaining it.

Comment: @user1165952 yes, just put the jquery code from the jsfiddle inside `$(document).ready(function(){` (which can also be written in shorthand like this: `$(function(){`. You can now delete `editRow()` if all that was doing was toggling the visibility of the save and cancel buttons. `toggle()` specifically refers to changing back and forth the `display` property from `display:none` to `display:inline`

Comment: @user1165952 Can you please remember to accept an answer when you are done?

Comment: I changed only editrow to jquery and left the remaining as JS. It's working now!!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding end spans to your content. This could help the reason why your additional rows are not being displayed properly.

```
<span id="edit_button_<?php echo $row[$id]; ?>" style="display:block;" onClick="editRow(this, '');"><img src="images/edit.png" /></span>
<span id="edit_save_<?php echo $row[$id]; ?>" style="display:none;" onClick="saveRow(this,'');"><img src="images/green_check.png" /></span>
<span id="edit_cancel_<?php echo $row[$id]; ?>" style="display:none;" onClick="cancelEdit(this, '');"><img src="images/red_cross.png" /></span>
```

Comment: sorry, </span> are already there, I just removed it to save some space here.. My bad :(